# Would Talos amulet work if equipped during cooldown?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't use shouts too often, so I rarely equip the Talos amulet. Still, I use to have the Become Ethereal shout equipped, just in case I have to use it in an emergency.

If I use the shout and equip the Talos amulet once the cooldown time is already activated, will the remaining cooldown time be shortened? Or are the cooldown bonuses only effective in the moment of shouting?

Comment: What did you observe when you tried that in-game?

Comment: I was expecting someone with those PC-magical-console-commands could provide some reliable information (I have xbox version), but I guess I will answer myself with my _research_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used my chronometer to measure the times and this is what I found out (as I should have done before asking, anyway):

Used Ice Form Shout (60 seconds cooldown), waited 30 seconds. Equipped Talos amulet, and still had to wait 30 more seconds of cooldown. The same with other shouts.

So Talos amulet is only effective **before the shout**. I guess I'll have to be fast if I want to use it in an emergency.